# Reenvío de fomulario

Tags: mvc, cakephp, controller

Se que esta pregunta ya la hice en el pasado, pero con la solución del pasado no hace nada este código, a lo que me refiero es que inserta el dato pero al recargar la pagina inserta de nuevo repitiendo los datos que ya se insertaron.
la version es la 2.x

este es el código del controlador:

```
$this->layout = "client";
$user = $this->Auth->user();
if ($user['rol'] === "client") {

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->loadModel('Need');
        $this->Need->create();
        if ($this->Need->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Your post has been saved.'));
            //$this->redirect();
            //return $this->request->data;
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your post.'));
        }
    }
    $this->set('user', $user);
    $this->loadModel('User');
    $informacionUsuarios = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('username' => $user['username'])));
    $this->set('informacionUsuarios', $informacionUsuarios['User']);
    $this->loadModel('Client');
    $informacionClientes = $this->Client->find('first', array('conditions' => array('email' => $user['username'])));
    $this->set('informacionClientes', $informacionClientes['Client']);
    $this->loadModel('Need');
    $informacionNecesidades = $this->Need->find('all', array('conditions' => array('client' => $informacionClientes["Client"]["company"])));
    $this->set('informacionNecesidades', $informacionNecesidades);
    $contadorNecesidades = $this->Need->find('count', array('conditions' => array('client' => $informacionClientes["Client"]["company"])));
    $this->set('contadorNecesidades', $contadorNecesidades);
}
```

No se por que se reenvía el formulario.

vista

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?php
                echo $this->Form->create('Need', array("class" => "form-signin"));
                echo $this->Form->input('client', array('label' => array('text' => " "),
                    'placeholder' => '¿Para que marca vamos a trabajar?',
                    'class' => 'validador txtClient lang prettyName', "type" => "hidden", 'key' => 'txtClient',
                    "value" => $informacionClientes['company']));
                echo $this->Form->input('process', array('label' => array('text' => " "),
                    'placeholder' => '¿Para que marca vamos a trabajar?',
                    'class' => '', "type" => "hidden", 'key' => 'txtClient',
                    "value" => "Empty"));
                echo $this->Form->input('date', array('label' => array('text' => " "),
                    'placeholder' => '¿Para que marca vamos a trabajar?',
                    'class' => '', "type" => "hidden", 'key' => 'txtClient',
                    "value" => date("j") . "/" . date("n") . "/" . date("Y")));
                ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <?php
                    echo $this->Form->input('need', array('label' => array('text' => "Escríbenos acerca de tu necesidad",
                            'key' => 'lblNeed', 'class' => 'lang'), 'placeholder' => 'Agradecemos nos detalles muy bien la necesidad, '
                        . 'es nuestro punto de partida para generar ideas quer fortalezcan la estrategia para resolverla.',
                        'rows' => '4', "minlength" => "900", "required" => "true", "maxlength" => "", 'class' => 'validador txtNeed lang prettyText validLength', 'key' => 'txtNeed', 'style' => 'resize: none;'));
                    ?>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <?php
                    echo $this->Form->input('objective', array('label' => array('text' => "¿Cuál es el objetivo?",
                            'key' => 'lblObjective', 'class' => 'lang'), 'placeholder' => 'Que se quiere alcanzar con la'
                        . 'solución de la necesidad, ¿Adquirir usuario? ¿Mejorar ventas? ¿Posicionar la marca? ... entre otros.'
                        . ' Agradecemos nos detalles muy bien el objetivo.', 'rows' => '4', "minlength" => "300", "maxlength" => "",
                        'class' => 'validador txtObjective lang prettyText validLength', "required" => true, 'key' => 'txtObjective', 'style' => 'resize: none;'));
                    ?>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Guardar')); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Al decir no hace nada ¿a que te refieres? agrega una descripción del comportamiento esperado y de lo que hace ahora, y también tu versión de CakePHP :)

Comment: @KacosPro ya actualice la pregunta